# scraping noise from front driver side when turning

Tags: brakes, noise

My car 2014 Audi RS5 AWD has started to make a scraping noise from the front driver side when turning. The noise has this interval, higher frequency in higher speed. The noise disappeared after replacing the brake pads but after a week it came back again and it seems to be getting worse and worse. What could be causing this?

This is someone else's video of the same noise but mine isn't as bad as this one though, at least not yet. https://youtu.be/nX1TOWUcits

Comment: Always turning or only at full lock?

Comment: Check the dust shield for rubbing.

Comment: Sometimes at full lock. Mostly just when slighting turning. Or sometimes when i release the brakes after stopping.

Comment: @Ben I am with Ben on this. You say the sound returned? Do you have a gravel driveway, or drive over rocky surfaces at all/often?

Answer (score 1):

Is your car front wheel drive if so check the cv joint. A rubber boot may be broken on the cv joint axle of a front wheel drive car. The brake pads may not be fitted properly.

Comment: It is an awd. 2014 audi rs5. We checked the cv joint and it looks fine.